# Finding max occurrence in ParseObject

Tags: android, parse-platform, nosql

I have two columns in my Parse database. The class is called `Nowcast`. The relevant columns are `Location` and `Weather`. There are multiple entries of `New York` under `Location` and `Weather`: `"rainy"` in some, `"sunny"` in a few others.

Can I write a `ParseQuery` to get the `Weather` data of the max occurrence of a certain type of weather in New York?

For example, if there are 4 `"sunny"` entries and 2 `"rainy"` entries in the database for New York, can I write a query to get `"sunny"` for New York?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These sort of aggregate queries are not supported by Parse's query language. You would need to query all the objects that match New York, and analyze the occurrence of each type of weather on the client.